# Calculating Area in Java; Order of Operations

Tags: java, math, operator-precedence, area

I'm trying to find the area of a Polygon using the following formula:

Area = r^2 n sin( 2 π / n) / 2

where n is the number of sides and r is the radius.  I do not think my code is producing the correct result.  If n= 6 and r = 4, i'm getting an area of 24.  My code is as follows:

```
import java.math.*;
```

public class RegularPolygon {

```
private int n; // number of vertices
private double r; //radius of the polygon

/**
 * This is the full constructor
 * @param n is the number of vertices
 * @param r is the radius
 */
public RegularPolygon(int n, double r) {
    super();
    this.n = n;
    this.r = r;


}

/**
 * default constructor.  Sets number of sides and radius to zero
 */
public RegularPolygon() {
    super();
    this.n = 0;
    this.r = 0;

}

//getters and setters for Number of vertices "n" and radius "r".

public int getN() {
    return n;
}

public void setN(int n) {
    this.n = n;
}

public double getR() {
    return r;
}

public void setR(double r) {
    this.r = r;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "RegularPolygon [n=" + n + ", r=" + r + "]";
}

public double area(){
    float area;
    //this method returns the area of the polygon
    //Use Math.PI and Math.sin as needed
    return area =  (float) (Math.pow(r, 2)* n * ( Math.sin(Math.PI / n)/2));
```

It is unclear to me where my order of operations is messed up.

Comment: First of all, you don't need to declare a new float in your area method.

Comment: `Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / n)`

Comment: @forpas ok, so it should be **return  (float) (Math.pow(r, 2)* n * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / n));**

Comment: Don't cast to float

Comment: `Math.pow(r, 2)* n * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / n) / 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not translating the formula correctly. You need `return Math.pow(r, 2) * n * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI / n) / 2;` As forpas pointed out in the comments, you're missing a 2 and saying `Math.sin(Math.PI / n)` This has nothing to do with order of operations, since it's all just multiplication and division.

Answer (score 0):

You should not type cast to float as you have declared the return type of the method as double

```
return Math.pow(r,2) * n * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI/n) / 2;
```

I think the above code will satisfy your need.